# Outlook & VML different view

Tags: email, outlook, ms-office, html-email, vml

The root problem is to display nice button compatible with MSO. As I used VML its working perfectly one pc, and not working an another. The point is environment of both PC is same

Win 10 - Microsoft Outlook ( 16005.13110.41006.0 )
The button source code is

```
    <!--[if mso]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://google.com" style="line-height:28px; height:28px;width:135px; display: inline-block;" stroked="False" fillcolor="#468fb0">
        <center style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 11px;">
            CENTER
        </center>
    </v:rect>
    <![endif]-->
```

At mine it looks nice
[image]

In other PC
[image]

So

- Sizes are less in both dimensions
- No text inside
- Button is clickable

I tried different combination of VML/HTML tags, but it always the same - width&height ignored, and inner text is missing at all

If save emails as EML file and compare - its the same
Any suggestions what can be trigger this styling?

Other links and styles working properly btw.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was a weird but
The problem was in pixels ( maybe screen resolution related? )
Every size with `px` was less. Solved with replace sizes to `pt`

Comment: it has to do with the magnification i would say. Your PC might have 100% and others might have it at 125 or 150%. points would fix it yes.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed Campaign Monitor's '[bullet proof button](https://buttons.cm/)' has this `<w:anchorlock/>` before the `<center>` which appears to function as an internal mechanism to stop anchors (links) from being modified. Maybe that's it?

I.e.

```
<!--[if mso]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://google.com" style="line-height:28px; height:28px;width:135px; display: inline-block;" stroked="False" fillcolor="#468fb0">
<w:anchorlock/>
    <center style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 11px;">
        CENTER
    </center>
</v:rect>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: sad, but no effect

Comment: I'm not sure you can have `display: inline-block;` - try removing that. Outlook generally doesn't regard changes to display.